# Split text inside list

Tags: python

I have a list that has the following structure:

```
input =
[['Business']
 ['Technology']
 ['Technology Business Sports']]
```

I'd like to split sentences into words and create the following structure:

```
result =
[['Business']
 ['Technology']
 ['Technology', 'Business', 'Sports']]
```

I tried this

```
result = input
for i, s in enumerate(input):
    result[i] = s[0].split()
print(result)
```

But I get the error:

> ValueError: cannot copy sequence with size 2 to array axis with
>   dimension 1

Comment: Looks as though you are using NumPy arrays, not Python lists.

Comment: The code above works with lists. The answers work with lists too, but probably not with numpy arrays

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want something like this:

```
>>> data = [['Business'],
...  ['Technology'],
...  ['Technology Business Sports']]
>>> 
>>> [inner[0].split() for inner in data]
[['Business'], ['Technology'], ['Technology', 'Business', 'Sports']]
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
input = [['Business'], ['Technology'], ['Technology Business Sports']]
output = []
for elem in input:
    output.append(elem[0].split(" "))
```

Output:

```
[['Business'], ['Technology'], ['Technology', 'Business', 'Sports']]
```